# Eigen3: Writing out sparse matrix

Tags: c++, c++11, eigen, eigen3

I have created a sparse martrix in Eigen3 using the following code:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Sparse>
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/MarketIO.h>
#include <vector>

using SpMatrix = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;
using S = Eigen::Triplet<double>;
using namespace std;
using AdjacenyMatrix = SpMatrix;

int main() {

    vector <S> nonzero_compenents;
    AdjacenyMatrix am(10, 10);
    nonzero_compenents.push_back(move(S(1, 1, 1.0)));

    am.setFromTriplets(nonzero_compenents.begin(), nonzero_compenents.end());

    bool s = saveMarket(am, "/home/morris/Schreibtisch/sparse_matrices");

    return 0;

}
```

Unfortunalty, the code does not compile. There is seems to be something wrong in `MarketIO.h`:

```
In file included from /home/morris/sparse/main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/MarketIO.h: In function ‘void Eigen::internal::PutMatrixElt(Scalar, int, int, std::ofstream&)’:
/usr/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/MarketIO.h:87:9: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}’ and ‘int’)
     out << row << " "<< col << " " << value << "\n";
         ^
```

...
Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't use MarketIO, but the MarketIO.h header ( avaliable [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/MarketIO_8h_source.html) ) uses fstream but does not include the <fstream> standard header. So, try #include <fstream>, and remember that its unspecified which std headers a std header includes ...

Comment: You are not supposed to directly include MarketIO.h, but the module `unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra`. BTW, it is not a good idea to include `eigen3/` in your `#include` directive because Eigen's headers are not necessarily within a `eigen3` folder.

Answer (score 0):

As @ggael said: Don't include individual files but the module/directory containing them. Note that in this case you also need to drop the `src` from the path.

Previously:

```
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/MarketIO.h>
```

Now:

```
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>
```

Full code:

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Sparse>
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>
#include <vector>

using SpMatrix = Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;
using S = Eigen::Triplet<double>;
using namespace std;
using AdjacenyMatrix = SpMatrix;

int main() {

    vector <S> nonzero_compenents;
    AdjacenyMatrix am(10, 10);
    nonzero_compenents.push_back(move(S(1, 1, 1.0)));

    am.setFromTriplets(nonzero_compenents.begin(), nonzero_compenents.end());

    bool s = saveMarket(am, "/home/morris/Schreibtisch/sparse_matrices");

    return 0;

}
```

Now it should compile using for instance

```
g++ -std=c++11 mycode.cc
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
#include <fstream>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>
```

instead of

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Sparse>
#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/MarketIO.h>
```

the code compiles

**Note**: `#include <eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/SparseExtra>` does not compile